# CouchDB find paired documents and list remaining unpaired documents

Tags: javascript, transactions, mapreduce, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm relatively new to NoSQL, but I have been enjoying the journey very much! I am however finding the map-reduce way of life a bit tricky! I need some help with a problem!

I have a database with two types of documents, opening transactions and closing transactions.  For replication and offline functionality reasons I **cannot** merge the data into one document.  The opening transaction document looks something like :

```
{
  _id: "transaction-open-randomgeneratedstring",
  type: "transactions-open",
  vehicle: "vehicle-id",
  created: "date string"
}
```

The closing documents looks something like:

```
{
  _id: "transaction-close-randomgeneratedstring",
  type: "transactions-close",
  openid: "transaction-open-randomgeneratedstring",
  created: "date string"    
}
```

The `randomgeneratedstring` of a closing transactions match the `randomgeneratedstring` of the corresponding opening transaction.

I need a map-reduce to give me the list of open transactions that does not have a corresponding closing transaction.  This will basically give me a list of outstanding transactions.

This is the map-reduce I have thus far, but it is not doing the job.

```
{
  "map": function(doc) {
     if(doc.type == "transactions-open") {
      emit([doc._id, 0], "OPEN");
     }
     if(doc.type == "transactions-close"){
      emit([doc.openid, 1], "CLOSE");
     }
  },
  "reduce": function(keys, values, rereduce) {
    var unique_labels = {};
    var open = {};
    keys.forEach(function(label) {
     if(!unique_labels[label[0]]) {
      unique_labels[label[0]] = true;
     } else {
      open[label[0]] = true;
     }
    });
    return open;
   }
 }
```

I am open for changes in the _id naming / structure, but I cannot combine the two documents into one.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Based on response from Hod, I changed the reduce to look like:

```
function(keys, values, rereducer)
{
  if(values.length == 1)
   return true;
}
```

This is certainly a step in the right direction, but the unwanted transactions are still in the result set, the value is only null.  Is there no way to get those out of the result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described - what you would do with a Join in SQL you do with a reduce in CouchDB. Code something like this - not tested:

```
 {
  "map": function(doc) {
     if(doc.type == "transactions-open") {
      emit([doc._id], 1);
     }
     if(doc.type == "transactions-close"){
      emit([doc.openid], -1);
     }
  },
  "reduce": "_sum";
 }
```

So we emit a 1 for an open transaction under an ID and a -1 for a close under the same ID. Now when you reduce you will get a result for each ID of:

- -1 = Closed with no record of an open (error condition).
- 0 = Opened and Closed
- 1 = Open and not yet closed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `keys` parameter in your reduce function.  The reduce phase is not called once with all possible keys.  It's called per distinct key, and based on the group_level you specify.

Looking at your code, if you haven't specified any group_level, your reduce function is going to get called for every document separately.

Because you're emitting the id of the open transaction doc for both open and close markers, if you grouped at the first level, you'd get open or open/close pairs.  You're still only getting a reduction on a limited set of docs at a time.

You could fix this either in your logic calling the query, or by emitting a key that let's you reduce on the entire set at once.  (I imagine there are other ways too.  These are the ones that come to mind.)

If you use the key approach, you'd need to emit something that looked like `["transaction", doc._id, 0]`.  Then a first level grouping would give you the whole transaction set like you're current code expects.

**EDIT** (Adding information based on edit of question.)

The reduce function is going to get called with whatever grouping you set up.  It's always going to return something, even if it's just no results emitted (i.e. null).

If you don't want to handle that in the logic that's running the queries and processing the results, you need to use an approach that will allow you to group all the transaction documents together, instead of just the documents for a single transaction.

Based on what you've done so far, another approach would be to forgo the reduce phase and just look at the number of results returned by a query that's limited to the unique doc id.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have shed a lot of light on how the reduce function works! In my map, the doc._id for open and the doc.openid for closed are the same. If I group at level 1 I will then get both transactions in the reduce? What will happen if I do not return anything in the reduce for instances where the length of the keys > 1?

Comment: Yes, grouping at level 1 should bundle the two docs for a completed transaction into one reduce call.  Returning nothing or a zero length array will work.